# optional parameters FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

please help me. In the function I set the optional parameter `param` as a boolean value, but the docs (swagger) do not display the data type for param. How to fix it? I'm using `python 3.12.1`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from datetime import date


app=FastAPI()



@app.get ("/sales")
def sales(
    date_from: date, 
    date_to: date,
    param: bool | None  = None,
):
    return date_from, date_to, param
```

[image]

on version `python 3.9` everything is fine

Comment: If it works with Python 3.9 but not 3.12, it's probably a bug in FastAPI. You should open a [github issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set the optional parameter "param" as a boolean value, but the docs do not display the data type

Well, it's not a `bool`, is it?
You decided to make it a `bool | None` instead.
(Sometimes pronounced `Optional[bool]`, same thing.)

Let's fix that:

```
    param: bool = False,
```

Comment: I understood it. what to do with this parameter, it is also not displayed, example from the documentation `q: Annotated[str | None, Query(max_length=50)] = None`

Comment: It appears you're going to have to make some compromises. If you really want swagger docs (a lovely goal), and swagger offers a least-common-denominator type system that is less powerful than what `mypy` and [beartype](https://pypi.org/project/beartype) support, then maybe just cry "Uncle!" and do what swagger demands. Which in this case is probably sticking with a simple `str` type. // It's possible that you could have private "strictly typed" helper functions behind the scenes, which swagger doesn't care about. And then you call through to them and mostly get the best of both worlds.

Comment: this is a pydantic problem, I tried installing pydantic version 1.10 and it worked. json for Swagger is different. Now I don’t know what to do, should I use the old or new version of pydantc?

Comment: `q: Annotated[int | SkipJsonSchema[None], Query()] = None` Using SkipJsonSchema removes anyOf and null from openapi.json and swagger shows parameter correctly

Comment: SkipJsonSchema,            FTW!

Comment: `from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema`